# Is it possible to reload a Quip Document lightning component on a lightning page without reloading the entire window?

Tags: quip, lightning-page

I have a Quip document embedded in the Account lightning page within a tab. I am updating the Quip URL field on the Account on click of a button in a different tab. However, once the page is loaded, any update on the URL field is not reflected on the Quip tab.

I have tried using `$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();` but it does not refresh the Quip component.

Is there a way to achieve a quip component reload without reloading the entire browser window ?